# reading a text file and multiplying the first line by each of the other lines

Tags: c#, arrays, split, streamreader

i'm working on this homework and i need to read a text file of integers, store the numbers into arrays. Then square the numbers in each line (after 25) and then divide the square by 25 and then check if the result is bugger than 150

Where i'm stuck is reading the numbers of each line and using them in my method like i'm supposed to, so far my loop and arrays prints put each number in the file in order.

i'd really appreciate any help with the array part, Thanks.

Here is the text file:

```
25   150
60        
63
61
70
72
68
66
68
70
```

so, take `Math.Pow(60,2) / 25`, and `Math.Pow(63,2) / 25` and so on. then if it is higher than 150, print "yes" and print "no" if it is lower than 150

here is what i have:
i have another class

```
class Resistors
{
    //declare variables for the resistance and the volts.
    private  int resistance;
    private int volts;

    public Resistors(int p1, int p2)
    {
        resistance = p2;
        volts = p1;
    }
    //GetPower method.
    //purpose: to get calculate the power dissipation of the resistor.
    //parameters: it takes two intigers.
    //returns: the total power as a double.
    public double GetPower()
    {
        return (Math.Pow(volts, 2) / resistance);

    }
}
```

and here is the rest.

```
static void Main(string[] args)

    //declare some variables and an array.
    const int MAX = 50;
    string inputLine = "";
    Resistors[] resistor = new Resistors[MAX];
    //declare a counter and set to zero
    int count = 0;

    // This line of code gets the path to the My Documents Folder
    string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
    (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";
    WriteLine("Resistor Batch Test Analysis Program");
    WriteLine("Data file must be in your Documents folder");
    Write("Please enter the file name: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // concatenate the path to the file name
    string path = environment + input;

    // now we can use the full path to get the document
    StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path);

    while (inputLine != null)
    {
        inputLine = myFile.ReadLine();
        if (inputLine != null && count < MAX)
        {
            string[] data = inputLine.Split();
            int dataR = int.Parse(data[0]);

            string[] pie = inputLine.Split();
            int pieV = int.Parse(pie[0]);


            resistor[count++] = new Resistors(dataR, pieV);
        }
    }
    WriteLine("Res#\tDissipitation\tPassed");

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {

        WriteLine("{0:d}\t{1:N}", j + 1, resistor[j].GetPower());
    }

    ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you need :

### Edit:

Based on your comments, if you want to read multiple values on the first line, you can separate them by a comma, and then split on.

```
25,150
60        
63
61
70
72
68
66
68
70
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    // This line of code gets the path to the My Documents Folder
    string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";
    Console.WriteLine("Resistor Batch Test Analysis Program");
    Console.WriteLine("Data file must be in your Documents folder");
    Console.Write("Please enter the file name: ");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // concatenate the path to the file name
    string path = environment + input;

    // Will read all lines
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
    // Will get the first line arguments and split them on the comma, you add more arguments if need, just separate them by a comma
    var firstLineArgs = lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t))
                                .ToArray();
    // Will skip the first line arguments and parse all the following numbers
    var numbers = lines.Skip(1)
                       .Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t))
                       .ToList();

    // Will create each Resistors object with the first line arguments (25) and the actual number
    // You can do whatever you want with the second arguments (150)
    var resistors = numbers.Select(t => new Resistors(firstLineArgs[0], t))
                           .ToList();  

    Console.WriteLine("Res#\tDissipitation\tPassed");

    foreach (var item in resistors)
    {
        // Check if item.GetPower() is greather firstLineArgs[1] (150)
        // I don't know what you want to do if it's greater
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}\t{1:N}", resistors.IndexOf(item) + 1, item.GetPower());
    }

    Console.ReadKey();     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped a lot and it work for the most part. What would i need to do to if there was another number next to 25 in the same line, so if i needed to divide by that 25 and then let's say add 50. How do i read two numbers in the same line.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment and last question update. Telle me if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Let me took few lines from you code:

```
if (inputLine != null && count < MAX)
    {
        string[] data = inputLine.Split();
        int dataR = int.Parse(data[0]);
        string[] pie = inputLine.Split();
        int pieV = int.Parse(pie[0]);
    }
```

You are actually doing the same this with split(); and also `Split()` is not necessary there, you can achieve the same with `int dataR = int.Parse(inputLine);` and `int pieV = int.Parse(inputLine);`

From the example you mentioned in the question

> take Math.Pow(60,2) / 25, and Math.Pow(63,2) / 25 and so on.

You have to assign the first value in the file as `resistance` if so( and i understand correctly) you can do the whole by using the following code:

```
List<string> stringArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"filePath").ToList();
List<int> intList= stringArray.Select(x => x!=null || x!="" ?0:int.Parse(x)).ToList(); 
//Now `intList` will be the list of integers, you can process with them;
int resistance=intArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < intArray.Count ; i++)
{
  resistor[i] = new Resistors(intArray[i], resistance);
}
```

You can try with your code too :

```
StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(@"path_here");
const int MAX = 50;
string inputLine = "";
// Resistors[] resistor = new Resistors[MAX];             
int count = 0;
int resistance = 0;
while (inputLine != null)
{
    inputLine = myFile.ReadLine();
    if (inputLine != null && count < MAX)
    {
        int inputInteger = int.Parse(inputLine);
        if (count == 0) { resistance = inputInteger; }
        resistor[count++] = new Resistors(inputInteger, resistance);
    }
}
```

Comment: As much as I am a Pro-Linq user, I think the OP might find it too complex for a mere homework :)

Comment: yes haha, i appreciate all the help. This is my first programming class and it's just the fundamentals of programming so most of the code used in the answers here, are things that we haven't cover and probably won't for a while. It does help a lot tho. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that the code you have written calls your Resistors constructor with the 1st and 2nd line of your input file, then with the 3rd and 4th lines, then with the 5th and 6th lines ...

Your description suggests that you want to retain the first line then use it in construction of each Resistor object.  Perhaps I have misunderstood your problem.  You might want to consider showing a few points of output against a few points of expected output.

Also your 'inputLine.Split()' is unnecessary.  you can just parse the inputLine string.